# Is it possible to create an instance of a class in VB from a string containing the class's definition?

Tags: visual-studio, vb5

Is it possible to create an instance of a class in VB 5 CCE from a string containing the class's definition?

Um... I'm actually using VB 5 CCE because I'm too cheap to get a version that costs money. Can someone tell me how to implement it that way?

TYVM to whoever answers this!!!!!

NVM... I'm downloading VS 2008 Express...

Comment: Boy, haven't heard about CCE for a long time :).  You do know that nowadays we have Visual Studio Express Edition that is free and allow you to do a lot more in .NET framework, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("ClassName")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like given a string with the following value: "Public Class Foo:Public Sub Bar():End Sub:End Class" and you want something like Dim the class = Eval(theString) and do something with your new class, see [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/198/evaluate-string-formulas-in-vb/).

They do it by extending it in VBScript.